# ARFCN, TMSI, IMSI on android

Tags: android, gsm

I'm trying to extract the ARFCN TMSI and IMSI from an android phone connected to a gsm network. There is no documentation in the Android API to do so. I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to get any of this information. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`TelephonyManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) to get some basic information about the telephony services including the [IMSI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSubscriberId%28%29), but TMSI and other info may be unavailable.

Comment: Thanks for that. Would it be possible to query the RIL directly to get the ARFCN and the IMSI? if so how would that work?

Comment: For an un-rooted device, it looks highly unlikely because there is no public API. You could take a look at this discussion on [android-platform Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/b55c8d3275ed7042/ca8ce1494ff90e45?#ca8ce1494ff90e45)